# zoom in on a portion of a table in beamer

Tags: tables, beamer, presentations, zooming

I have a very large table on a beamer slide that I want to show the audience first (so they get a sense of the whole thing) but then I want to zoom in on particular portions of that table. How can this be done? Furthermore, can I have a zoom in effect to transition between the zoomed slide and the non zoomed slide?

Thanks

Comment: Have you read the section on anticipated zooming in the manual? If you continue to have trouble, please include a minimal working example in your question. (Very nearly almost) All questions should include an MWE, as you presumably know by now.

Comment: i haven't. let me look at that portion of the manual. i needed a place to start, will include a MWE in the event it's unclear. thanks!

Comment: The linked question concerns zooming in on an image, but it just happens to be an image. It isn't doing anything with the image to get the zoom. Essentially, your question is exactly the same: how to zoom on part of a slide, regardless of content. (As opposed, say, to the use of the `spy` library, which would only work straightforwardly for certain kinds of pictures.)

Comment: except i would like a transition between the zoomed and unzoomed version...

Comment: Aren't transitions usually a matter for the PDF viewer? Different viewers support different kinds of transitions.